# NestJS how make subdomain routes?

Tags: node.js, rest, routes, nestjs, bad-request

Please tell me how in NestJS you can process a route like this (without params):

- hostname.com/users/password/edit  or
- hostname.com/users/password/new

How to properly organize transition processing on 'edit' or 'new'?

I'm getting this so far:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Validation failed (numeric string is expected)",
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```